# Techniques for supporting schema based evolving XML in C++

Tags: c++, xml, xslt, xsd

I'm currently designing a special-purpose-application in **C++** which has to deal with XML-files that come with **evolving XSD-schemes**.

- This application will need to be supported quite a while in the future, the need to support newer versions of the XML-files is very likely.

The main challenge is: the input-XML files come with XSD schemes which are basically similar 
(they are all different versions of the same definition standard of configuration data), but differ in terms of structure and even naming.

- Not all of the data contained in the files is needed right now, tho this may change!
- Currently the data only needs to be read once the application start, tho this may change!
- Currently the data only needs to be read, not written back, tho this may change!

## Facts

- XML-files may be as big as 200MB.
- XSD-schemes have 500+ lines of pure code (no comments).
- Right now I need to support at least 3 different versions (out of 10+).
- The XML-parser, which is going to be used has to be namespace aware.
- A change log of the versions exists, but sadly is incomplete and very little precise.

## Up to now following considerations have been made:

### Using databinding for each version

[Code Synthesis XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) offers a nice DOM/SAX based parser and data-binding generator.

- leads to a huge (really big) code base
- interfacing of generated classes needed
- future-proof?

### Using a SAX-parser with version-based handlers

By utilizing a sax-parser like Apache Xerxes, the version-specific code may be placed in sax-callback-handlers.
These callback-handlers may be hidden trough a 'VersionReaderFactory' which returns the correct handler for a certain version of the XML file.
The handlers would fill the data into generic data classes which contain the necessary configuration data.

- read only!

### Using XSLT to transform old XML

[Altova](http://www.altova.com/) offers a nice XSLT-processor which may be used to transform old versions of the XML-defined configuration data into the newest version.
After this transformation has been performed, a 'simple' databinding may be used to access the data as there is only one version to support.

- need to create a XSL-transformation for each version.
- creating transformation code is error-prone.
- it is unclear if all entities of all versions may be transformed at all. (incomplete changelog)

### Using XPATH

Having XML as underlying format, XPATH would be a natural choice for querying data.
A 'home-brew-parser' could utilize some 'VersionReaderFactory' that returns a set of predefined XPATH-queries for a certain version of the XML file.
This 'home-brew-parser' would fill generic data classes with the necessary configuration data.

- could be successively extended to fit the requirements
- read only!

## Questions

- Which part of the application should be version-aware?

  ```
    XML             |    Parser               |    Application
    close to data   | beneath the application | in the application
  ```
- Which of the described methods would do best in your opinion?
- Are there other options?

Comment: Did you try the `C++/Tree` or the [`C++/Parser`](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/c++/parser/) API of CS XSD?

Comment: Yes, I've done some testing with XSD, but so far my main concern is where to do the version-handling.

Comment: (XSD is definietly going to be used if a data-binding approach is chosen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrospectively, following methods turned out to be sufficient for 99% of what I needed:

1. Method: "version hopping"

   For each version of the given XML-files /XSD-schemes that needed to be supported, a XSL-Transformation has been created to convert the given input file up to the next version, finally a XML-C++ data-binding as been generated using Code Synthesis XSDe.

   whenever a new version needs to be supported, only one XSLT stylesheet has to be added to the preprocessor, and the code-generation is basically automated - a couple of UnitTests are in place for each version to ensure supporting a new version doesn't break the support for legacy files.
2. Method: "extaction of required data"

   For each version of the given XML-files/XSD-shemes that need to be supported, a XSL-Transformation has been created to convert the given input file into another filetype which only contains the required data.

   by using such an approach, a simple XML scheme or even a well known key-value store filetype such as json may be used to collect the wanted data.

   whenever a new version needs to be supported, only a single new XSLT file has to bee added to the preprocessor, the resulting output file stays the same among all versions.

the preprocessor for both methods could be created with XLST 2+, run on Saxon HE.